# Highcharts bar chart tooltip HTML positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I am working with highcharts at the moment, I have a tooltip on by bar chart that is being cut off by a `overflow:hidden` setting, this is fine and understand I need that setting however the positioning of the tooltip is not overly intelligant, is there a way to position the tooltip relative to the width of the column, i.e if the tooltip is going cause a scrollbar can I decrease the offset? I don't have a code example, but I have attached an image of my problem,

[image]

Comment: You can move the tooltip as need by providing a function to the `positioner` property: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.positioner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use tooltip positioner function in your tooltip. Adjust tooltipX and tooltipY accroding to your display requiremets :

```
    positioner: function(labelWidth, labelHeight, point) {         
                         var tooltipX, tooltipY;
                            if (point.plotX + labelWidth > this.chart.plotWidth) {
                                tooltipX = point.plotX + this.chart.plotLeft - labelWidth - 40;
                            } else {
                                tooltipX = point.plotX + this.chart.plotLeft + 40;
                            }
                            tooltipY = point.plotY + this.chart.plotTop - 20;
                            return {
                                x: tooltipX,
                                y: tooltipY
                            };       
                    }
```